# Google teardrop patented

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-desktop, google, license

We want to indicate a point on a map and like the idea of using a teardrop but it seems that google has the teardrop idea patented (http://www.google.com/patents/USD645052 http://www.google.com/patents/USD661704 http://www.google.com/patents/USD620950)  Does this mean that even if we create our own, unique teardrop shape that we would be violating the patents that google has on the tear drop shape?  Obviously it wouldn't look like googles, but it would look similiar since it would be a teardrop shape.  Any other ideas on a good point marker?  We are using Esri's tools, not google maps.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that anybody except a Lawyer can truly answer your question. Having said that, I have seen plenty of webmaps with teardrops. I think they ever are the default marker in Laflet. See the map on this page: http://leafletjs.com/

Comment: I don't see how this is related to GIS.  This is a patent issue, not a question about GIS.

Comment: There are many other free alternatives for icons http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/ is one active and good source

Comment: Area 51 of Stack Exchange now has a proposal for Legal Questions called [**Life**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44823/legal-questions) - perhaps try this one out there.